# What is the difference between connAttemptCount and reconnAttemptCount of a TibjmsConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, tibco-ems

The [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.1-march-2013/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/TibjmsConnectionFactory.html#setConnAttemptCount(int)) has the following:

setConnAttemptCount - attempts - The number of times the connection object attempts to establish a connection to the server.

setReconnAttemptCount - attempts - The number of times that a connection object attempts to reestablish a connection to the server.

Is the connAttemptCount the initial attempt and the reconnect after it has connected and lost connection?

There are a few other properties wrt to connect and reconnect but I guess once the obove is answered I will know the other as well:

```
 <bean id="tibcoJmsConnectionFactory" class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="serverUrl" value="${tibco.server.url}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${tibco.user}"/>
    <property name="userPassword" value="${tibco.password}"/>
    <property name="connAttemptCount" value="2"/>
    <property name="connAttemptDelay" value="100"/>
    <property name="connAttemptTimeout" value="1000"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptCount" value="4"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptDelay" value="100"/>
    <property name="reconnAttemptTimeout" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  The [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.1-march-2013/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/index.html?com/tibco/tibjms/TibjmsConnectionFactory.html) for the `setReconnectAttemptTimeout()` API call explains the need to have separate configuration settings for reconnections versus initial connections:

> This parameter is similar to setConnectAttemptTimoeut The difference is that it may be necessary to use different parameters during reconnect than during the initial connect. Initial connect of the clients to the server is normally distributed in time and there are less chances of the server exceeding its maximum accept queue. During fault-tolerant switch, all connected clients automatically try to reconnect to the backup server, approximately at the same time. When the number of connections is large, it may require more reconnect time to reconnect than the initial connect.